# MySQL command(s) to create user

Tags: mysql, database

How can i achieve the following in MySQL?

Type the command(s) necessary to create a user called `myuser`. The user should have the password `mypass`, and should not be allowed to access the database from any device by `PROD-DB1`.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? There is good documentation about it. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to create a new user in mysql command line :

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

So for you :

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

And to revoke permission :

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* FROM '<user_name>'@'localhost';
```

Comment: I did try myself. The confusing part of this question for is the "should not be allowed to access the database from any device by PROD-DB1". Does that mean the user cannot be allowed to access the database called PROD-DB1 from any device?